# What's the purpose of "Send all traffic over VPN connection" in OS X

Tags: macos, vpn

In OSX (im running 10.10.5) what dose the option "Send all traffic over VPN" mean in the VPN network settings. Dose this mean that all LAN traffic would also be sent ?

[image: screenshot of network tab]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will send only client (1 computer) traffic to the tunnel, and it won't cover the whole LAN unless your OSX is a gateway and masquerading.

If you enable it, it will encrypt all the data, and your IP will display the server's IP address instead of ISP.

If you disable it, it is called split tunneling. It will still communicate with the server and accessible remotely through the server, but your IP stays the same. Ideal for when you don't want to send all traffic to the server and experience slow internet connection.

Comment: I have it enabled yet my external IP is still local, not the VPN server's to which I’m connected. strange